# Reset wp-options and export specific wordpress settings and options

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog with `wp-options` table contain about 1900 records it contains a lot of plugins theme option that already removed.. I tried to delete theme one by one but it seems too difficult I want to reset the table with a fresh one.

But I need to keep actual plugins and theme options.

Is there any way to export and import specific wordpress, plugins and theme options? And what is the best way to reset a wordpress table?